# Can't open TCP channel on Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, tcp, virtual-machine

I have an Azure Virtual Machine running, and I have the following logic in a Windows Service that I coded up that hosts a WCF TCP endpoint with a MEX HTTP endpoint as well:

```
    private void OpenTCPChannel()
    {
        string fqdn = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").HostName;
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None, true);
        binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxConnections = int.MaxValue;
        binding.ListenBacklog = int.MaxValue;
        binding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
        binding.ReliableSession.Ordered = true;
        binding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
        Uri serviceAddress = new Uri(String.Format("net.tcp://{0}:{1}/GameServer", fqdn, Properties.Settings.Default["GameServerPort"]));
        ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(service, serviceAddress);
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IGameService), binding, serviceAddress);
        ServiceMetadataBehavior metadataExchange = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        metadataExchange.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        metadataExchange.HttpGetUrl = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/GameServer", fqdn, Properties.Settings.Default["MEXPort"]));
        serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadataExchange);
        serviceHost.Open();
        log.WriteEntry(String.Format("Successfully started TCP endpoint at {0}.", serviceAddress.ToString()));
        log.WriteEntry(String.Format("Successfully started MEX endpoint at {0}.", metadataExchange.HttpGetUrl.ToString()));
    }
```

The code runs perfectly well when I test locally, but when I run my service and open my TCP channel on my Azure VM, I can't access my MEX endpoint for some reason.

I'll try navigating to: `http://<MyServiceName>.cloudapp.net:<MEXPort>/GameServer` but I can't grab a service reference from that address. Is there something that I've missed in terms of how to provision an Azure VM to allow tunneling out from a local port to the outside world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh my god, it was so poorly documented, but I had to add rules to the ports in Windows Firewall on my VM.

Start -> Windows Firewall with Advanced Security -> Right-Click on Inbound Rules -> Add Rule...create a new Port rule for the ports you've specified in the Endpoints section of your Azure Management Portal (the online portal)...